# bad number Error KSH Script

Tags: unix, ksh

I am very new to Unix and this is one of my first scripts. I cannot seem to resolve this bad number error, and have searched for an answer online. I have not had much luck so I though I would turn here. Can someone help me out, I keep getting this :bad number error for both variables. Here is my script, thanks!:

```
#!/bin/ksh

dest=$1 

fileName=$2

id=$$

print_message()
{
   message="$1"
   echo "`date '+%m-%d-%y %T'`  $message" 

}


if [ $1 -eq "" ] ||  [ $2 -eq "" ]

        then 
        print_message "Parameters not satisfied"
        exit 1 
fi 



gpg --encrypt --recipient "$dest" "$fileName"


print_message "$id INFO: File Encrypted Successfully"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
if [ $1 -eq "" ] || [ $2 -eq "" ]
```

Use `=` instead of `-eq`, the latter is meant for numbers rather than strings.

You may also need to wrap quotes around the possibly empty arguments, such as `"$1"`.

Comment: @user2640213, my apologies, that should have been a single `=`, I've fixed it up. Guess I've been using the `bash` `[[` for too long :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've user `-eq` which is meant for numerical values. You need to use `=` for strings. Your code should look like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

dest=$1 

fileName=$2

id=$$

print_message()
{
   message="$1"
   echo "`date '+%m-%d-%y %T'`  $message" 

}


if [ $1 = "" ] ||  [ $2 = "" ]

    then 
    print_message "Parameters not satisfied"
    exit 1 
fi 



gpg --encrypt --recipient "$dest" "$fileName"


print_message "$id INFO: File Encrypted Successfully"
```

Easy mistake to make :)